# hostapd dynamically show/hide ssid

Tags: wifi, router, ssid, bssid, hostapd

I'm trying to implement a simple connection saturation algorithm for a bunch of nodes running `hostapd`.  On having `max_num_sta` connections, I want `hostapd` to move into hidden SSID mode (`ignore_broadcast_ssid=0`).  I have updated `src/ap/beacon.c` to include a simple conditional statement and recompiled successfully, but my SSID still keeps showing up when the node is "saturated":

```
if ( hapd->num_sta >= hapd->conf->max_num_sta){
  hapd->conf->ignore_broadcast_ssid = 1;
}else{
  hapd->conf->ignore_broadcast_ssid = 0;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Bummer there are no answers because I just came face to face with the 7-station limit of the Atheros TP-Link (USB 0cf3:9271) stick and hostapd. I need 9+ devices to be on wifi at the same time. when number of connected stations reaches 7, further stations get rejected in the most ugly way - prompted for password, says password failed while trying to join the network. Instead I'd rather hostapd stop broadcasting its SSID and responding to probe requests when it is at capacity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the configuration of the `bss` once you've edited it.

Try invoking `hostapd_reload_bss` (in `src/ap/hostapd.c`) for each defined `bss`. Note that if you choose to invoke `hostapd_reload_config`, all currently connected stations shall be deauthenticated, so don't do that.